# how can i add special charcter like breckets[ ], single quote ' double quote" in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can insert the special characters fine when using PHPmyAdmin, but it just doesn't work when inserting them via PHP. Could it be that PHP is changing the special characters into something else? If so, is there a way to make them insert properly?

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name); this is not work...
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

> Usage of utf8 in database collation is required for storing the values.

1.) `mysql_real_escape_string()` -  This will avoid up the SQL Injection.

2.) `htmlspecialchars` - This will prevent XSS attack.

Comment: Also, don't use `mysql_` functions at all - this extension is deprecated in PHP 5.6 and removed in 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote, like so:

```
'Women\'s Development & Empowerment, Youth Affairs'
```